# Cumbrian sources

Tags: english, resource-request, dialects, dictionary, vocabulary

I'm interested in the cumbrian dialect, but I couldn't find good sources of vocabulary and pontual aspects of its grammar. Also, I was trying to understand the following poem:

I'll tell the'
We're nut stuck up er prood i't mooth
Fer t'main on us was bred in't fells,
We're nobbut wiet, yammly, fwoak
Off t'seeam switch as yersels.

An' like yersels, we clag tight tull
0't bits o'country ways an' looar;
We like ta hod a crack aboot
T'auld dale-fwoak' at hev gone afooar.

Mi fadder, (an' nea doot he's reet),
Sez t's main o't' fell fwoak er o't seame
They "Hawk tagidder" on a drag,
Till Foxy's brush is hung on t'beame.

He sez 'at t' interest (like t' auld Fox)
Is rousan 'noo fer thee an' me,
Soo join, yersels, an git yer kin
Ta join oor own Society.

I found many of its words impossible to understand and I couldn't find any dictionary or glossary on their meanings. Do someone knows where can one find a good source of cumbrian?

Comment: I don't find this off-topic. It's asking for sources on grammar and vocabulary.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://www.cumbriandictionary.co.uk/

Comment: Grammar: Prevost and Dickson Brown 1905 https://books.google.com/books?id=luEOAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 1):

Well, googling one of the lines brought me to the Lakeland Dialect Society which has a [Glossary page](https://www.lakelanddialectsociety.co.uk/glossary) so I shall attempt a translation:

```
I'll tell you
We're not stuck up nor proud in the mouth
For the majority of us was bred in the fells [hills], 
We're nothing but wiet [?], homey, folk
Of the same such as yourselves.

And like yourselves, we stick tight to
our bits of country ways and lore;
We like to have a crack [talk] about
The old dale-folk that have gone afore [before].

My father, (and I don't doubt he's right),
Says most of the fell folk are all the same
They "Hawk together" on a drag, [Hawk = hunt?]
Till Foxy's brush is hung on the beam.  [Foxy's brush is the tail of a fox]

He says that the interest (like the old Fox) 
Is rousan not for you and me, [??]
So join, yourselves, and get yer kin
To join our own Society.
```

Comment: _wiet_ = quiet, _hawk_ = hunt (yes), _rousan 'noo_ = rising/rousing/roused(?) now (the apostrophe probably belongs to the end of _rousan_ rather than the beginning of _noo_)